# How to pause a docker container then reboot host system and unpause container?

Tags: debian, docker, container

Need to restart host os but how to save the state
of the running containers and after the host system
rebooted restore the containers from saved point?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45153855/9998715

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure Docker for experimental options:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/docker/daemon.json
```

add

```
{
"experimental": true
}
```

Press CTRL+X, select Y and press Enter to save the new file.

or

```
$ sudo echo '{"experimental": true}' >> /etc/docker/daemon.json
```

restart the docker service:

```
$ sudo service docker restart
```

Check with

```
$ docker version
```

if experimental is indeed enabled.

Install CRIU package

```
$ sudo apt-get install criu
```

Try out simple scenario with Docker checkpoint on CRIU

```
docker run --security-opt=seccomp:unconfined --name cr -d busybox /bin/sh -c 'i=0; while true; do echo $i; i=$(expr $i + 1); sleep 1; done'
```

check on the values:

```
docker logs cr
```

create a checkpoint for the container:

```
docker checkpoint create  --leave-running=true cr checkpoint0
```

leave the container running for a while and check the logs again

```
$ docker logs cr
```

now stop the container:

```
$ docker stop cr
```

and restart/recreate the container from the checkpoint:

```
docker start --checkpoint checkpoint0 cr
```

Check the logs:

```
docker logs cr
```

You will find that the log is resumed at the value where the checkpoint was created.

https://technology.amis.nl/2018/04/08/first-steps-with-docker-checkpoint-to-create-and-restore-snapshots-of-running-containers/